# Splitting a string using a regexp that matches more than one character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to achieve the following for both `@` or `#`.

```
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/@/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
```

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the point of that code?

Comment: What is the problem? What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: There's no jQuery in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
val.split(/@|#/g);
```

The `|` is the regex alternation operator ie 'OR'. The `g` flag makes the expression match globally (ie all instances)

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLsfc/)

As Pointy notes the `g` flag isn't necessary here. It is however necessary if wanting to find all matches within a string in JS regular expressions.

Comment: Drat, beat me to it because I did not post 30 chars :(

Comment: I don't think the "g" suffix is necessary, as `.split()` already implicitly searches for all occurrences of the pattern.

Comment: @Pointy I won't even bother checking as you're always right! :)

Comment: hat's great! thanks! now I actually need to know which one it was?

Comment: Hold on I'll check - I'm not quite so confident in me :-) ... it works fine for me without the "g".  Be aware, @Steeve17, that splitting on a regular expression can be, or at least could be in the past, a little flaky. [Here](http://goo.gl/YqwLT) is a somewhat old blog post on the topic. It may be the case that modern browsers are more reliable.

Comment: @Steeve17 How do you mean which one?

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/[@#]/g);
}
```